# How can I observe the attribute lookup chain in Python?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I am trying to delve into Python's class descriptors, and have come across an article explaining the lookup chain of class attributes. Namely, it is said that the first priority is the `__get__` method of the data descriptor (that is, a class that implements `__set__` or `__delete__` method. Then comes the **dict** of the object followed by **get** method of non-data descriptor.

This seems extremely confusing to me, and I am hopeless to find a real example demonstrating how, say, data descriptors come before **dict** lookup of an instance. I would really appreciate a minimum example with `print`s that illustrates this theoretical stuff.

Comment: See https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/. It contains several very useful flow charts.